# how to display vertical tab in screen mode?

Tags: linux, terminal, special-characters, gnu-screen

I have a file contain these text

```
abc\v\rdef
```

if i cat the file in shell mode, it presents like the following. it's correct.

```
abc
def
```

if i cat the file in screen mode, it presents like the following. it's wrong.

```
def
```

all commands i input was posted

> **$ cd /tmp**
> **$ cat test.txt**
>   abc
> def
>   **$ screen**
> **$ cat test.txt**
>   def

*how to let vertical tab display correctly in screen mode?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cat -v` to display nonprinting characters. See `man cat` for details.

Another option is to use `tr`:

```
tr '\v' '\n' < test.txt
```